# Button text doesn't visible after adding an image to its image property in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, background-image

I have a button.I have added an image to its image property and also to its background image property.Now it only display the button with added images and can't see button text.What is the reason.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do accept the answer which helps u .By clicking on the check mark below

Comment: just set background image.. [btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and chk your btn text_color is not same as image color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the background image is fine but when you set the button.image property, it is overlaid over the textfield that the button has so you do not want to add an image to that property if you plan on using the buttons text.

Comment: There is no textfield as part of UIbutton , there is only UILabel .

Comment: So,that means if I add button image,Then I can't see button text.If so,Is there any other way to visible both of them(button's image and text) ?Do I need to create the image with text ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant uilabel, if you can get away with only setting a background image, just do that, if not then ur best bet is to set text on the image in photoshop but that's not really good practice in case you want to change the text.  Why don't you just set the background image on the button?

Answer (score 1):

you have to play with the `EdgeInset` property of the `UIButton` to properly align the content of the button (title an image)

Answer (score 0):

use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method of `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

[image]You have to add image to background if you want to add title later or else use image with text.
Put image in background image just below image if you do it through nib

Comment: So is that means,to visible both image and title,I have to use image with text ?

Comment: No no just set title and put image in background not in image